# spark changing dataframe to rdd : column order changes in RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

When converting DataFrame to javaRDD the column order in rdd changes. It's not the same I used in select statement while creating dataframe .

Please help how can I maintain the column order after changing DataFrame to javaRDD.

Comment: Post the code please, I have never seen this happen